# Dymanically load regex patterns from conf

Tags: c++, regex

I have a C++ application that should:

1. Dynamically load regex patterns from a conf file
2. Scan a argument passed in during the call of the application for any matches to the regex pattern
3. If any matches are found to that regex pattern, replace them with [REDACTED]
4. Output the 'clean' version of the text

I am stuck getting the regex patterns loaded from the conf.

I have the conf file configured so that each line should be a regex pattern (comments are just #). I have this being read correctly into an array defined as `string* g_Regex = new string[255]` (it is a global var).

I am able to pull the patterns into a string properly, but defining a regex object is not working for me.

```
bool matchRegex(string haystack) {
    bool matchFound = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(g_Regex); i++) {
        if(std::regex_match(haystack, std::regex(g_Regex[i]))) {
            g_Matches[i] = 1;
            matchFound = true;
        }
        else {
            g_Matches[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return matchFound;
}
```

So I've identified that I am defining the regex pattern incorrectly. I am doing:
    std::regex(g_Regex[i])

I should be doing:
    std::regex r(g_Regex[i)

The only issue I have is that there is an undefined number of regex patterns, and I don't know how to 'dynamically create' variables, or if thats even what I need to do.

Could someone much smarter than me look into this and perhaps help me figure out how to set this up properly?

[Edit]
I removed the global variables and converted the string array to a vector. I am still having problems dynamically creating the regex patterns.
[/Edit]

[Edit 2]
Its definitely an issue with compiling the regex. I changed:

```
if(std::regex_match(haystack, std::regex(g_Regex.at(i))))
```

to

```
if(std::regex_match(haystack, std::regex("(.*)")))
```

And the application processes.

g_Regex is now `vector<string> g_Regex`
[Edit 2]

Comment: You might want to use something like `std::vector<std::string> g_Regex` rather than `string* g_Regex = new string[255]`.

Answer (score 0):

To start, global variables are bad.

You should be just using an std::vector to hold the regexes if you don't know how many regex patterns you will need at runtime, as you probably don't want to deal with having to resize your array dynamically.

Additionally, you should store the compiled regex inside of the vector instead of the raw string to avoid recompiling them on each loop.

Comment: I can change my app to not use global variables. Thats fine.
I am also changing my app to not use a string array, but rather vectors, and I have no problem storing the compiled regex inside of the vector as long as I can A) get the regex pattern as a string and B) figure out how to do this. I still run into the original question, just in a different spot in my app.